# Loading a config file into a script

Tags: python, volttron

In a Python volttron agent, I get an error on the function return when trying to load a config file through `def ahutrimrespond(config_path, **kwargs)`. `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'dict'`

```
def ahutrimrespond(config_path, **kwargs):
    """
    Parses the Agent configuration and returns an instance of
    the agent created using that configuration.

    :param config_path: Path to a configuration file.
    :type config_path: str
    :returns: Ahutrimrespond
    :rtype: Ahutrimrespond
    """
    try:
        config = utils.load_config(config_path)
    except Exception:
        config = {}

    if not config:
        _log.info("Using Agent defaults for starting configuration.")


    # setpoints for AHU trim respond agent
    ahu_static_sp_start = float(config.get('ahu_static_sp_start', 1))
    ahu_static_sp_min = float(config.get('ahu_static_sp_min', 1))
    ahu_static_sp_max = float(config.get('ahu_static_sp_max', 1))
    static_sp_trim = float(config.get('static_sp_trim', 1))
    static_sp_increase = float(config.get('static_sp_increase', 1))
    time_delay_startup = float(config.get('time_delay_startup', 1))
    time_delay_normal = int(config.get('time_delay_normal', 1))
    ignore_requests = int(config.get('ignore_requests', 1))
    num_of_vav_above_hi_stp = int(config.get('num_of_vav_above_hi_stp', 1))
    high_vav_dpr_stp = int(config.get('high_vav_dpr_stp', 1))


    return Ahutrimrespond(ahu_static_sp_start, ahu_static_sp_min, ahu_static_sp_max, static_sp_trim, static_sp_increase, time_delay_startup, time_delay_normal, ignore_requests, num_of_vav_above_hi_stp, high_vav_dpr_stp **kwargs)
```

This is the config file below and entire agent [script on a gist](https://gist.github.com/bbartling/f164de4eb6b2200cc99e52950db90d60#file-ductpressureresetagent-py). Any newbie tips greatly appreciated.

```
{
  # setpoints for AHU trim respond agent
  "ahu_static_sp_start": 0.1, # "WC - AHU duct pressure start
  "ahu_static_sp_min": 0.15, # "WC - AHU duct pressure start min
  "ahu_static_sp_max": 1.5, # "WC - AHU duct pressure start max
  "static_sp_trim": -0.04, # "WC - AHU duct pressure setpoint trim amount
  "static_sp_increase": 0.06, # "WC - AHU duct pressure setpoint increase amount
  "time_delay_startup": 300, # seconds - wait time when agent is started before control
  "time_delay_normal": 120, # - seconds time delay between check of VAV dpr positions & trim respond
  "ignore_requests": 1, # - high end VAVs to discard immediately before trim respond calc
  "num_of_vav_above_hi_stp": 2, # - of VAVs above high_vav_dpr_stp to req to trim or resp AHU duct pressure stp
  "high_vav_dpr_stp": 90 # % - setpoint for num_of_vav_above_hi_stp to raise or lower duct pressure
}
```

This is the entire [error trace back](https://gist.github.com/bbartling/f164de4eb6b2200cc99e52950db90d60#file-error-txt).

Answer (score 0):

The OP forgot a comma between an argument and `**kwargs`, so it is interpreted as `high_vav_dpr_stp` to the power of `kwargs`, which doesn't work. `kwargs` is a dictionary.

```py
# ...
return Ahutrimrespond(
  ahu_static_sp_start, 
  ahu_static_sp_min, 
  ahu_static_sp_max, 
  static_sp_trim, 
  static_sp_increase, 
  time_delay_startup, 
  time_delay_normal, 
  ignore_requests, 
  num_of_vav_above_hi_stp, 
  high_vav_dpr_stp, # Add this commma
  **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks well that at least fixed that part of debugging :) Ill hit the green check when I can